# How to View Data from other SQL Server in kentico?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, kentico

i need to know the process of connecting something like (DataGrid / DataList webpart) in kentico from another database in SQL server not the current Database which i create it when i was setup Kentico for the first time ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use e.g. the "SQL Data source" web part. How to use data source web parts is described [in this part of documentation](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/using_datasource_web_parts.htm)